# Prove $\ell(\theta^{(t+1)}) \geq \ell(\theta^{(t)})$, answer proof not clear, need some expainations

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, self-learning

## Question

The problem is to proof the inequation, but the answer is too elliptical, can anyone give some comment or explaination to help me build up the logic chain?

[image]

## Answer

[image]

## The confusion part:

1. why (1) is not $=$.
2. (2) why they directly come up $\theta^{(t+1)} > \theta^{(t+1)}$.
3. is there missing something between (0) and (1)?